# Having trouble with try catch

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `asp:GridView` set up on the client side like so:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
            AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" CssClass="GV" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" 
            AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" AllowPaging="true"
            runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnection%>" runat="server">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then in the code behind I set the `DataKeyNames` and the `asp:SQLDataSource` arguments inside of try/catch statements. Even when I comment out the first try catch I cannot get the second one to fire.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string qs = Request.QueryString["param"];
    string id = Request.QueryString["id"];

    if (qs != null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (qs == "Department")
            {
                GridView1.DataKeyNames = new string[] {"id"};
                SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [table2] "
                    + "WHERE Department_Name LIKE'" + id + "' ORDER BY [Department_Name] DESC";
                SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE table2 SET Department_Name=@Department_Name, Phone=@Phone, "
                    + "Fax=@Fax, Contact=@Contact, Address=@Address, City=@City, State=@State "
                    + "WHERE (id = @id)";
                SqlDataSource1.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id = @id";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [table1]";
            //ApplicantsSqlDataSource.UpdateCommand = "";
            //ApplicantsSqlDataSource.DeleteCommand = "";
            GridView1.Visible = false;
            NoResults.Text = "<p>Sorry, there are no results that match your search query.<br />" + ex + "</p>";
        }
    }                   
}
```

here is the click event

```
protected void SearchDept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtSearchDept = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("txtSearchDept");
    if (txtSearchDept.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?param=Department&id=" + txtSearchDept.Text.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        NoResults.Text = "<p>Please enter a search parameter.</p>";
    }
}
```

it should work but it doesnt

**Edited**
here is the first try catch that is working that was originally left out

```
try
            {
                if (qs == "LastName")
                {
                    GridView1.DataKeyNames = new string[] {"EMPLOYEE"};
                    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [table1] "
                    + "WHERE Last_Name='" + id + "' ORDER BY [EMPLOYEE] DESC";
                    SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE table1 SET FIRST_NAME=@FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME=@LAST_NAME, "
                    + "TITLE=@TITLE, DATE_HIRED=@DATE_HIRED, WK_PHONE_NBR=@WK_PHONE_NBR, WK_PHONE_EXT=@WK_PHONE_EXT, "
                    + "EMAIL_ADDRESS=@EMAIL_ADDRESS, DEPARTMENT=@DEPARTMENT, PROCESS_LEVEL=@PROCESS_LEVEL, CELL_PHONES=@CELL_PHONES, FAX_NUM=@FAX_NUM "
                    + "WHERE (EMPLOYEE = @EMPLOYEE)";
                    SqlDataSource1.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE EMPLOYEE = @EMPLOYEE";
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [table1]";
                //ApplicantsSqlDataSource.UpdateCommand = "";
                //ApplicantsSqlDataSource.DeleteCommand = "";
                GridView1.Visible = false;
                NoResults.Text = "<p>Sorry, there are no results that match your search query.<br />" + ex + "</p>";
            }
```

Comment: The 2nd what? I only see one try catch. Be more specific in describing the unexpected behaviour. Which line throws an exception/is unreached?

Comment: Misuse of try-catch eh? Wouldn't you be better off with `emptydatatemplate` of the `gridview`?

Comment: you also have a MASSIVE sql injection exploit in your code. What if I set id='';delete from table2--. Your code would execute this without thinking. NEVER append user input directly to SQL & execute it. Never.

Comment: @DeeMac I decided to only post the one that was not working verses posting the entire code but forgot to remove it in my description. When I insert breakpoints I notice that the select statement comes up null.

Comment: @abhitalks the `datakeynames` are being set dynamically

Comment: @Skullomania wouldn't matter.

Comment: What exactly is the try/catch meant to be doing? I'm not even clear what exception is being thrown and caught... Perhaps you should let us know where you expect an exception to be thrown and why (or vice versa if one is being thrown that you don't expect). Also agree with others that this looks like program logic and not exceptional circumstances you are dealing with so you probably shouldn't be using exceptions.

Comment: You should really try removing both try/catch statements and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the percent sign in the `SelectCommand` of the Department area.

Follow the correct form : `SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [table2] " + "WHERE Department_Name LIKE '%" + id + "%' ORDER BY [Department_Name] DESC";`